# Spring Batch - How to customize Step Exit message description length?

Tags: spring-batch

Is there any environment variable or something how to change the `maxVarCharLength` like `tablePrefix` in `JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java`?

I couldn't find any config class where this setter method is called

```
public void setMaxVarCharLength(int maxVarCharLength) {
    this.maxVarCharLength = maxVarCharLength;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you to call this method in order to set the `maxVarCharLength` property. The `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` will then use the value you set to create the `JobRepository`. You can find an example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobRepository

Comment: The approach of creating custom `JobRepository` object by implementing `BatchConfigurer` interface is satisfying my requirement. Can we make it happen via environment variable? Because just for one value I do not want to write few more lines of code even if it autowires most of the details.

Comment: No, the code of `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` does not load properties from environment variables. You can still inject the property from the environment variable using Spring's environment abstraction and set in on the factory bean.